# Get Century from date in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

How can I get century from the year in a date field using SQL server query?

As, for example, the period 1901 - 2000 is 20th century. To get century, if I try to get the left substring of 2 and add 1 from the year, then how can I implement for the year '2000'?

Is there any function for getting century from date?

Comment: Did you put your post title into Google and look for answers?

Comment: Yes I did!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select 1 + (year(date) - 1) / 100 as century
```

or alternatively:

```
select (year(date) + 99) / 100 as century
```

Comment: Why not `1+(year(date) ) /100` ?

Comment: Because the century starts in 1901, not 1900.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly... **select 1 + (year(date) - 1) / 100 as century** Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

```
select CEILING(year::decimal)/100 as century
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.